# How to set default value for column in Google bigquery table using API from pyhton script

Tags: python, google-bigquery

Class that crate column and describe it doesn't have "default_value_expression" in the constructor.

path: google/cloud/bigquery/schema.py

```
class SchemaField:
def __init__(
name: str,
field_type: str,
mode: Any = "NULLABLE",
description: Any = None,
fields: Any = (),
policy_tags: Any = None)
```

That key is displayed on the [google bigquery docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/default-values#write_api).

But when I try to set the value for any column using this key the error message "Unknow key(s): default_value_expression..." is displayed.

I tried to set a default value from the google cloud console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you're using the latest version of the library.  It was just released in version [3.4.0](https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#340-2022-11-17) a few days ago.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I don't know why, but pip installed library version 2.**.*.